# Socket.io avoiding spam/exploit

Tags: socket.io, spam, exploit

I have a socket.io server that I use for chat and some real time displaying information on my website. The users have points to use on the site
 and I wanted to have a /send command for them to give some points to friends. And I made like this:

```
if (msg.substr(0,6) === '/send ') {
    msg = msg.substr(6);
    var ind = msg.indexOf(' ');
    if (ind !== -1) {
        var receiverID = msg.substr(0, ind);
        var amount = msg.substr(ind + 1);
        if (amount <= 0) {
            socket.emit('chat error', 'Error! The amount should be greater than 0!');
            return;
        }
        if (row[0].pontos < amount) {
            socket.emit('chat error', 'Error! You don\'t have this amount of points');
            return;
        }
        if (isNaN(amount)){
            socket.emit('chat error', 'Error! Syntax: /send userid amount');
            return;
        }
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `steamid`=\'' + receiverID + '\'', function(err35, row35, fields35) {
            if (err35) throw err35;
            if (row35.length == 0) {
                socket.emit('chat error', 'Error! You are trying to send coins to an unregistered user!');
                return;
            }
            var receiverSecret = row35[0].secret;
            if (receiverSecret == row[0].secret) {
                socket.emit('chat error', 'Error! What\'s the point of sending points to yourself?');
                return;
            }
        connection.query('UPDATE `users` SET `pontos`=`pontos`-\'' + amount + '\' WHERE `secret`=\''+row[0].secret+'\'', function(err350,     row350, fields350) {
                if (err350) throw err350;
            connection.query('UPDATE `users` SET `pontos`=`pontos`+\'' + amount + '\' WHERE `secret`=\''+receiverSecret+'\'', function(    err3500, row3500, fields3500) {
                    if (err3500) throw err3500;
                    updatePoints();
                });

            });
            clients[row[0].secret].emit('chat success', 'You\'ve sent '+amount+' points to '+row35[0].nome);
            if (receiverSecret in clients) {
                clients[receiverSecret].emit('chat success', 'You\'ve received '+amount+' points from '+row[0].nome);
            }
        });   
    }else{
        socket.emit('chat error', 'Invalid user id! Format: \'/send <userid> <amount>\'');
    }
}
```

How could I avoid a user from spamming this command and therefore preventing them from exploiting the site by pasting and sending it multiple times/second? I already tested it, I managed to send more than I have and be at negative points.

Comment: You'll need to check if user has more points available than the amount of points required to perform one /send that might be one out of a lot of other options...

Comment: As you can see in the code I posted in the question, I already check that, but when spamming, the mysql query can't run fast enough to respond to those commands

Comment: Here you're doing a non blocking side by side, you should check it first, then in the callback, should do an update.

Comment: You mean, if I put an `else` in the points<amount, would it do the job?

Comment: in node.js, 
    ```query(){
    }```
and
    ```second_query(){
    }```
Is executed in parallel if not nested, so when you're getting a result inside a callback, ```query({},function(err,data){})``` You need to perform second query from inside that function to make sure that you have completed the first query then proceed second query.

Comment: So, suposing that I have 3 nested queries. This could take let's say 100ms. What if the user spams that command and take like 90ms to type enter. What would happen to the function?

Comment: So it works like this: we send a message, first we check if he has enough points, if he does, ONLY THEN we let him send, else we can just discard it.

Comment: I know, but what happens if in this meantime he sends another message?

Comment: I wouldn't know much about that, I really think it'd be very difficult to do that, could you test if you can do that? And let everyone know?

Comment: a user could just ctrl+v and enter real quick multiple times. I think no database que perform queries this fast. I'd like to know how to avoid that

Comment: can* (i couldn't edit the comment above)

Comment: Nope, try it, if you're doing a ctrl+v, real quick, you wouldn't be able to be that fast, or why don't you use a queue? serve one request after a request is done.

Comment: I don't know how to do that. :/